# C++ Recursion Character Printing

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, character, cout

Edit: Corrected Code (Thanks for the answers and help!)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr1(const int n,int i, int j){
  if(j != 0) {
    /* if(i == 2*n ){
    cout<<"\n";
    --j;}*/
   if((i <=  (n-j) || (i >= (j+n)) && i <2*n)){
    cout<<" ";
   }
  if(i < n && i > (n-j)){
    cout<<"\\";
  }
  if( i > n && i < (n+j)){
    cout<<"/";

  }
  if(i == n){
    cout<<"v";

  }
  if(i == 2*n ){
    cout<<"\n";
    i = 0;
    --j;}
  return arr1(n,++i,j);

}
  return 0;
}

  int main(){
    int c;
    cin>>c;
    arr1(c,1,c);

  }
```

I'm trying to write a program that takes an integer n and recursively prints an arrowhead type design

```
n=1 ->  v
n=2 ->  \v/
         v

n=3 ->  \\v//
         \v/
          v
```

etc:

This is my code so far, yet I keep getting a segmentation error. I assume this because of an infinite loop somewhere in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int arr1(const int n, int i, int j)
{
    if (j != 0)
    {
        if (i == 2 * n)
        {
            cout << "\n";
            --j;
        }
        if (i <= n - j || i >= j + n)
        {
            cout << "_";
        }
        if (i < j)
        {
            cout << "\\";
        }
        if (i > j)
        {
            cout << "/";

        }
        if (i == n)
        {
            cout << "v";

        }
        return arr1(n, ++i, j);

    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int c;

    cin >> c;
    arr1(c, 1, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Evidently, `j` never becomes zero? Or at least not soon enough before you have a stack overflow due to excessive recursion of your `arr1` function.

Comment: So, I added this:                                                                                if(i == 2*n ){
    cout<<"\n";
    return arr1(n,1,--j);}                                          Now it prints, but there is still a formatting error.

Comment: Why does the decrement on j I have in the original code I posted not change the value of j? My thought was that it would decrement j and then reach the recursive step. part of my problem was also that I did not reset the counter i after j was changed.

Comment: Wow, yes, other than those few mistakes, my logic was completely off too. Just fixed it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision of whether to recurse comes down to the value of `j` -- but you receive `j` from `main`, and never modify it afterwards unless `i==2*n`, passing the exact same value when it calls itself recursively. So yes, that leads to infinite recursion (assuming you originally pass a non-zero value for `j`, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You logic in the `arr1` function is wrong, for example, if `c=3` in the beginning,

the i, j, n values in `arr1` will be in each iteration

```
i = 1 j = 3  n = 3
i = 2 j = 3  n = 3
i = 3 j = 3  n = 3
i = 4 j = 3  n = 3
i = 5 j = 3  n = 3
i = 6 j = 2  n = 3
i = 7 j = 2  n = 3
i = 8 j = 2  n = 3
i = 9 j = 2  n = 3
i = 10 j = 2  n = 3
i = 11 j = 2  n = 3
```

...

then it goes for ever until stack overflow.